# slack API - reaction_added

Tags: python, slack-api

I'm using following slack events python adapter:
https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-events-api
And the code from the tutorial doesn't work:

```
from flask import Flask
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter


# This `app` represents your existing Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)


# An example of one of your Flask app's routes
@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return "Hello there!"


# Bind the Events API route to your existing Flask app by passing the server
# instance as the last param, or with `server=app`.
slack_events_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET, "/slack/events", app)


# Create an event listener for "reaction_added" events and print the emoji name
@slack_events_adapter.on("reaction_added")
def reaction_added(event_data):
  emoji = event_data["event"]["reaction"]
  print(emoji)


# Start the server on port 3000
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(port=3000)
```

It doesn't react on any emojies. It looks like putting emoji is not an event...

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: No, it don't trigger event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
From api.slack.com -> bot page -> Event Subscriptions -> Subscrive to Bot Events -> add "reaction_add"